How do I turn off swiping on selected elements?
Is there a way to turn off swiping on selected elements? I use UI Kit front-end and would very much like to exclude some sliders from swiping on mobile devices. Documentation seems not to give such flag or setting. Maybe some core editing will work?

Place another elment on top of slider.
